# kendo.widgetInstance throws exception TypeError: t is undefined

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to use kendo.widgetInstance() to get an instance of a kendo control:

```
$.each($('#AttributeForm').find(':input'), function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).closest('.k-widget').length > 0) {
        var widgetObject = kendo.widgetInstance($(element), kendo.ui);

        if (typeof widgetObject != 'undefined') widgetObject.enable(false);
    }
});
```

However, the kendo.widgetInstance() function is always throwing an error, TypeError: t is undefined.

This code is adapted from the following page:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/widgets#getting-reference-to-an-unknown-kendo-ui-widget

Using the 2013.2.918 version.

Is this the correct way to get an instance of a kendo widget?  All I want to do is disable all the kendo widgets inside the form and there are several different types but I don't know how many or what type they are.

Updated to show the correct way to disable a kendo control and the final code that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect, at least for this version of Kendo UI. `kendo.widgetInstance` requires a second parameter (the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#methods-widgetInstance) currently states this parameter is optional). Depending on whether you use Web or Mobile, the necessary parameter is `kendo.ui` or `kendo.mobile.ui`. So you need to change your call to:

```
var widgetObject = kendo.widgetInstance(widgetElement, kendo.ui);
```

See it work:
http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/798Rd/